# PHP pg_query update statement

Tags: php, pq

I am trying to updata a database table using pq_query in PHP. I have the following code:

```
$q = "UPDATE tableName SET ('data1 = " . $data1 . "', data2='" . $data2 . "') WHERE user=".$user;
$success = pg_query($q); 
if (!$success) { 
    $errormessage = pg_last_error(); 
    echo "Error " . $errormessage; 
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'data1 = '"
>
> LINE 1: UPDATE tableName SET ('data1 = 10', data2= 20'') WHERE user=

Comment: try this "UPDATE tableName SET (`data1` = '$data1', `data2`='$data2') WHERE `user`='$user';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace your query with this query**

```
$q = "UPDATE tableName SET data1 = '$data1', data2='$data2' WHERE user='$user'";
```

**Explaination**: You should pass variable in single quotes('') if your query in double quotes.

Comment: Please add an explanation, so OP get an idea why it happened!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lot of quotes which it is not understood by PostgreSQL, try simply this :

```
$q = "UPDATE tableName SET data1 = " . $data1 . ", data2=" . $data2 . " WHERE user=".$user;
```

Remove those single quotes !

Comment: Please add an explanation, so OP get an idea why it happened!